# Object has no attribute in flask-jwt-auth

Tags: python, angular, jwt

I am trying to use angular 4 and python to create a stateless login token. I am following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/token-based-authentication-with-flask/), but it is the first time I am using python and I am a bit confused.

The error I see when I try to test the method up to a point is:

> File "G:\Users\Administrator\flask-jwt-auth\project\tests\test_user_model.py", line 20, in test_encode_auth_token
>       auth_token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
>   AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'encode_auth_token'

This is my `test_user_model.py`:

```
import unittest
from project.server import db
from project.server.models import User
from project.tests.base import BaseTestCase


class TestUserModel(BaseTestCase):

    def test_encode_auth_token(self):
        user = User(
            email='test@test.com',
            password='test'
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        auth_token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(auth_token, bytes))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And this is `models.py` where `encode_auth_token` is actually defined.

```
import datetime
import jwt

from project.server import app, db, bcrypt


class User(db.Model):
    """ User Model for storing user related details """
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

def __init__(self, email, password, admin=False):
    self.email = email
    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
        password, app.config.get('BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS')
    ).decode()
    self.registered_on = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.admin = admin  
def encode_auth_token(self, user_id):
    """
    Generates the Auth Token
    :return: string
    """
    try:
        payload = {
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=5),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            'sub': user_id
        }
        return jwt.encode(
            payload,
            app.config.get('SECRET_KEY'),
            algorithm='HS256'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

I would appreciate all the help I could get as I understand this is a very specific question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the indenting of the methods `__init__` and `encode_auth_token` are correct?

Comment: `__init__` and `encode_auth_token` should be properly idented

Comment: @ikkuh i think so. At first I got the `unindent does not match any outer indentation level` error but now seems the problem is somewhere else.. is there a way to check if indenting is correct?

Comment: You are currently defining the methods outside of the `User` class. This means `User` objects don't have a `encode_auth_token` attribute (see error). Try indenting the `__init__` and `encode_auth_token` methods with 4 spaces.

Comment: yeah that was the problem... i was using tabs instead of spaces... apparently they are not the same think in python....

Comment: Maybe consider using an extension that handles jwt for you, such as flask-jwt-extended